# How to make a static_args property for a callable class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to see some concepts about static_agrs property for the python class. But i didn't remember the detail and I can't find any relevant documents online.
I have a callable class.

```
class Test:
    def func(self):
        print("Hello there")
        
    def __call__(self, fn: Callable):
        fn()
        print("This is a test calss.")

test = Test()
```

I want to dome something like this:

```
g = func() ##this is another callable
test(aux=1)(g)
```

so I can obtain the static args via `*self.static_args` and use the `aux=1` when the class is initialized. Could anyone tell me what's the exact concept of this or how to make it?

Comment: `def __call__(self, *args): self.static_args = args`. You can combine or replace with `kwargs`. Wouldn't it be better to use closures or factory methods for sth like this?

Comment: hmm @WörDuSchnaffzig actually the input for the class Test are callable functions, is it okay to make it *args?
for example ```g = func() test(aux=1)(g)```

Comment: Can you update your question with some words about how you pass the callables to the class?

Comment: That's a classical use-case for closures. You can do this more simple without using a class. Please read here: https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/ . The point is, that after calling g() you don't need that args again. So it's pointless to store them as instance variables.

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig the problem is that I don't have this option in my project. That's why i am looking for static agrs.

Comment: The closures approach should also work for methods. However, I wanted to keep my answer as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this using a closure:

```
import functools


def capture_args(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs)

def test_function(x, y, *, kw1):
    print(x, y, kw1)


prepared_func = capture_args(test_function, 100, 50, kw1=20)

> prepared_func()
> 100 50 20
```